# What is the name of this determinant or matrix?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, terminology

What is the name of this determinant or matrix?

$$\begin{vmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} \end{vmatrix}$$

Anything further explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's the Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Hessian matrix and it is used in determining the shape of a 2-dimensional function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Stay safe